# получение данных из 1с в с#

Tags: c#

Нужно написать программу чтобы получить данные(таблицы) из 1С в с#.примерно так же как брать данные с базы данных access.чтобы они отображались в datagridviev и с ними можно было работать
как это реализовать?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под работать? Читать? Или писать/изменять?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov выводит данные из 1 с в datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты:

1) С использованием COM устанавливаете соединение с базой, и получаете нужную информацию. При этом нужно знать объектную модель конфигурации 1С. Вариант подходит для 1С и 7-ой и 8-ой версии.

2) Если версия платформы старше 8.2 (не помню был ли реализован этот функционал в 8.1), то в конфигурации 1С можно реализовать метод веб-сервиса, который по запросу будет возвращать требуемые данные. С моей точки зрения, самый надежный вариант.

3) Если 1С развернута в клиент-серверном варианте (например, на Microsoft SQL), то можно узнать имя таблиц с нужными данными и брать информацию из них напрямую. Этот вариант теоретический и использовать его нельзя, т.к. структуру таблиц 1С генерирует аатоматом и она может меняться.

Comment: Заинтересовал второй способ,видел как с помощью OData это делают,но там очень плохо обьясняет мужик.и у меня возникла проблема когда захожу в публикацию веб клиента в 1с,он пишет что веб сервисы не обнаружены

Comment: Если честно, интеграцию через OData на практике я не использовал. Но, судя по всему, это отличный вариант для вас. Проблема с публикацией веб-сервиса на 1С? На чем публикуете? У меня с IIS постоянные танцы с бубнами. С apache никогда проблем не было (только 1с работает не со всеми версиями).

Comment: я в 1с полный ноль.поэтому не понимаю. там сервер создавать надо или как это происходит?

Comment: Да нет. Веб-сервер разворачиваете обычным способом. После этого в Конфигураторе 1С уже можно опубликовать базу. Примеры: для Apache https://infostart.ru/public/646384/ , для IIS https://infostart.ru/public/275820/).